# Inconsistent error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code. In a nutshell- I have two files a reader and a data. I need multiple users to be able to access these files, but they are stored on a Box account, so the file directory is different for each user. I have created the code that SHOULD do this. It runs perfectly when I step through the code by hand using <kbd>F8</kbd>, or even pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> after the workbook is open. However I need this to run on workbook open. When I open it I get the following error:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

This happens at the

```
Set directoryRange = ImSapMacroWorkbook.Worksheets("Users").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastUser, 2))
```

I have no idea why it happens at this point, but it is not consistent so I haven't been able to pin down why this happens. If it matters this is the first sub run in the auto_open sub. No variables are even declared before this runs.

```
Sub GrabData()
    Dim DataWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim ImSapMacroWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim pasteRange As Range
    Dim directoryRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim lastUser As Integer

    lastUser = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Users").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    Set directoryRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Users").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastUser, 2))
    Set MacroWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    On Error GoTo nextUser
    For Each c In directoryRange

        Set DataWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(c.Value)

        Exit For
nextUser:

    Next c

    LastRow = DataWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    Set copyRange = DataWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 36))
    Set pasteRange = MacroWorkbook.Sheets("input").Cells(2, 1)

    Call clearData

    copyRange.Copy
    MacroWorkbook.Activate
    pasteRange.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem- I ran

```
 DataWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").activate
```

in front of the portion that was giving me problems. Seems to have fixed it- will wait to confirm for a few runs since it was inconsistent anyway.

Comment: definitely seems to have solved the problem- will confirm as correct answer in 2 days when stackoverflow will let me.

Comment: Be aware that `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Users").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastUser, 2))` is equivalent to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Users").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2), ActiveSheet.Cells(lastUser, 2))` so if the active sheet is not "Users" then there will be an error. Using a `With ... End With` block can prevent this kind of error